# Prime zeta zeros - reference

Tags: reference-request

Is there an online repository for zeros of the prime zeta function? I looked at the Yahoo group 
[Prime numbers and primality testing](http://groups.yahoo.com/group/primenumbers/files/Pari-GP%20code/pzeros.txt) listed on the MathWorld notebook for the prime zeta function, but the group is restricted. Is there any open source access to such a list anywhere?

Comment: When you say the "prime zeta function" do you mean the "derivative of the Riemann Zeta Function"? If so, I have compiled a list of zeros which I can share with you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function .

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I can't find a ref to those zeros on that page - am I not looking carefully enough?!

Comment: @martin: My comment was on Rick Farr's answer, meanwhile converted to the comment above. I was directing him to the proper definition of the prime zeta function, which is not the derivative of Riemann zeta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems they were hidden deep in the notebook download from the Mathworld page all along! [*Here is a link to them*](https://github.com/martinq321/Prime_Zeta_Zeros/blob/master/zero_values) for ease of reference.